# SFML - getting text from sf::Text

Tags: c++, sfml, stdstring

I'm trying to get sf::Text value into a std::string with no success.

Here is the line of code :

```
std::string s = input_text.getString();
```

Does someone knows why this doesn't work?

It also says something about symbols from sfml-graphics-d-2.dll not being loaded ..

I am getting this error:

Debug assertion failed!

Expression : _pFirstBlock == pHead

If someone has a solution I would be thankfull.

Comment: sf::Text::getString(); doesnt return a std::string, look at the documentation.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann yes but how can I get the string value from the sf::Text?

Comment: That line of code looks OK to me since there is an implicit case from `sf::String` to `std::string`. `_pFirstBlock == pHead` hints at a heap corruption of some sort, perhaps from mismatched versions of the msvcrt. (Either mixing versions, or mixing debug and release.) In fact, here is [someone with a similar issue](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=15787.0) who fixed it by making sure SFML was compiled with the same version of studio as their project.

Comment: Yes I know there is a implicit conversion .. @SeanCline Would it work also with SFML 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

**getString()** returns SFML wrapper of string, use **.toAnsiString()**

```
string str = input_text.getString().toAnsiString();
```